# Installing Full Text Search to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, installation, sql-server-2008-r2

I installed sql server 2008 R2 Express successfully, then realised I need to get Full Text Search. So I downloaded the "[Advanced Services Installation Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25174)", but when I run it there is no option in the "Feature Selection" part for Full Text Search. Please don't tell me I hav to uninstall and reinstall?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, unfortunately you'll have to install a new instance with the Advanced Services installation. In R2 you can only add features such as Full Text Search if you initially installed with the advanced services installation.

You could backup your database though and restore it to the new installation w/ Full Text Search.  Or I think also detach/attach.

Comment: This was not working with the SP1 version of the Advanced Services package :(

Answer (score 6):

Its a two step process.

1. In the installer select Maintenance/Edition Upgrade to upgrade your existing instance.
2. Run the installer again and select Installation/...or add features to an existing installation/Add features to an existing instance.

Comment: Sorry, tried this, no luck

Comment: For SP1 version of the Advanced Services package, this did work, but for new instance (step 2). If you even go to existing instance option, you will see the features vanished and will requires restart of setup to get the features back for new instance..